# How to install Cisco-AnyConnect-64bit.tar.gz?

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, tar

I've read the question [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030/244993)
But it is said that after extracting, I should have files like `install`, `install.txt` or `README`.

`Make sure you read a file called INSTALL, INSTALL.txt, README, or something similar if one was extracted. You can check if such a file exists from the terminal by using the ls command. The file can be opened and read with the command:`
`xdg-open INSTALL`
`Where INSTALL is the name of your file. This file will contain the right steps to follow to continue the installation process.`

But there's not such file. 7 of the files which contain the word `install` in their name, have the extension `.sh`. The file `acinstallhelper` is in type of a program. There's no file named `README`

[image]

Comment: Please don't add text as screenshot's. Insert as text and format correctly.

Comment: Have you considered just using the AnyConnect compatible VPN client plugins and using your AnyConnect config with that VPN client plugin for NetworkManager?  That might be the easier approach.

Answer (score 1):

Well, those are *generic* instruction for a *generic* `.tgz` package.

I found a quite simple guide [here](http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~jstern/uci_vpn_ubuntu/) on how to specifically install Cisco AnyConnet on Debian/Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco AnyConnect How To - Linux

1. Download the `.gz` install archive from https://anyconnect.springernature.com
   to the desktop `anyconnect-linux64-4.9.01095-predeploy-k9.tar.gz`
2. Extract the archive to the desktop in the following folder `anyconnect-linux64- 4.8.03052-predeploy-k9.tar.gz`
3. Open a terminal window and navigate to the extracted folder in the terminal — for
   example, `cd ~/Desktop/ anyconnect-linux64-4.9.0.1095/vpn`

   Type `sudo ./vpn_install.sh`

   And `cd ~/Desktop/ anyconnect-linux64-4.9.0.1095/posture`

   Type `sudo ./posture_install.sh`
   When prompted enter your `root` password. Agree to the license agreement. The installation should now start and walk you through the setups.
4. In some Linux version you might need to install `libgtk2.0-0`
5. After installation if you can’t start AnyConnect client you need to reboot your Linux.
   After successful installation
   Start Cisco AnnyConnect Secure Mobility Client and type `vpn.springernature.com` in the line
   “Ready to connect“ (pic. 1) and click Connect. Then choose “SpringerNature” from the dropdown
   menu (pic.2) and log on using your AD credentials. After a successful log on all connection entries will
   be downloaded automatically. Next time when you want to log on choose **SpringerNature-Int** or
   other VPN Connection entries depending on where you are located.

Comment: This is useful, just I think spinger nature isn't needed, as we need to supply the URL of the company, not always spinger nature. Thank you